# Getting random data from grouped data in one table

Tags: database, random, sqlite

Here is the situation. I have one database table with the columns below:

- `PATIENT_ID`
- `PATIENT_GROUP`
- `FIRSTNAME`
- `LASTNAME`
- `ADDRESS`

I want to get `PATIENT_ID` randomly from certain `PATIENT_GROUP`.

There are 5 `PATIENT_GROUP` only with total row in the table is about 10000 (10K).
The number of data per `PATIENT_GROUP` is not the same. Certain `PATIENT_GROUP` has less data than the others. Do you know the **fastest** possible SQL query for this task? By the way, I am using SQLite3.

When there is no `PATIENT_GROUP`, I could come up with this query:

```
SELECT PATIENT_ID FROM TB_Patient 
WHERE rowid >= (ABS(RANDOM()) % (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM TB_Patient)) LIMIT 1
```

What's your best approach to solve this? The objective is the fastest possible query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the following query with different `<group_id>` according to the patient_group you are running on:

```
SELECT PATIENT_ID 
FROM TB_Patient 
WHERE PATIENT_GROUP = <group_id> 
ORDER BY RANDOM() 
LIMIT 1
```

I am not sure it is faster but it should be more easy to work with.

Good Luck!